# Injecting a C# Forms application into another application

Tags: c#, .net, forms, dll, code-injection

There are plenty of answers how to inject a DLL into another process. 
How would I do the same thing with an C# Forms application (exe) instead of a DLL.

Basically I want it to run in the virtual address space of another process. 
First I allocate the Memory, then I create remote thread. Now how do i get my existing exe to run in there? Also are there any limitations to that, (could i have it running inside explorer.exe for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it quite awhile ago for my own unmanaged app (without any injection - not that it matters). Once you've got your unmanaged DLL injected into the desired app's address space, you should create a dedicated thread, initialize COM on it (with `CoInitializeEx` or `OleInitialize`), then do the following (error checks skipped for brevity):

```
HMODULE hmodMscoree = LoadLibrary(_T("mscoree.dll"))

HRESULT (STDAPICALLTYPE *pCorBindToRuntimeEx)(LPCWSTR pwszVersion, LPCWSTR pwszBuildFlavor, DWORD startupFlags, REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR *ppv);
GET_PROC_ADDRESS(hmodMscoree, CorBindToRuntimeEx);

CComQIPtr<ICorRuntimeHost> m_host;
pCorBindToRuntimeEx(NULL, NULL, 0, CLSID_CorRuntimeHost, IID_ICorRuntimeHost, (void**)&m_host);
m_host->Start();

CComQIPtr<IUnknown> unk;
m_host->CreateDomainSetup(&unk);
CComQIPtr<mscorlib::IAppDomainSetup> domainSetup;
unk->QueryInterface(&domainSetup);
domainSetup->put_ApplicationBase(curDir);

CComBSTR appName;
ParseParam(m_commandLine, CMDLINEOPT_APPNAME, &appName);
domainSetup->put_ApplicationName(appName);

CComBSTR config;
ParseParam(m_commandLine, CMDLINEOPT_CONFIGFILE, &config);
domainSetup->put_ConfigurationFile(config);

unk.Release();
m_host->CreateDomainEx(m_managedApp, domainSetup, NULL, &unk);
CComQIPtr<mscorlib::_AppDomain> appDomain;
unk->QueryInterface(&appDomain);
appDomain->ExecuteAssembly_2(m_managedApp, &m_exitCode);
```

Make sure all dependency assemblies (if any) are available in the base folder (`curDir` in my code).

**EDITED**: That was done for .NET 2.0. I don't know if anything has changed since then. You could find more info on CLR hosting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx).

**EDITED**: `GET_PROC_ADDRESS` does just this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    #define FUNC_T(func) func##W
    #define GET_PROC_ADDRESS_T(mod, func) \
        ((FARPROC&)p##func = ::GetProcAddress(mod, #func "W"))
#else
    #define FUNC_T(func) func##A
    #define GET_PROC_ADDRESS_T(mod, func) \
        ((FARPROC&)p##func = ::GetProcAddress(mod, #func "A"))
#endif
```

You'd also need to #include `fusion.h` and `mscoree.h` (can be found In Windows SDK) and #import `mscorlib.tlb` (for .NET 2.0 it was `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb`).

Comment: So if it's not injected what does it do? Start up an exe normally?
Sorry just trying to understand your post.

Comment: I just added a few more lines to my answer. It should not matter if it's injected code or not, as long as you have your own thread, and the main app keeps running (i.e., `ExitProcess` has not been called). The above code will start the managed app on that thread, and the app will create its own message loop.

Comment: I'm a beginner in C++. It's telling me "identifier "GET_PROC_ADDRESS" is undefined". What dependencies do I need for your code?

Comment: Thanks, well C++ isn't really working out for me, I still have lots of unidentified dependencies. I appreciate your effort though and it might help someone else it the future so I'm selecting your answer as solved.

Comment: No problem. That piece was a part of big project and I cannot upload the whole thing, but here's [another sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953836) for you, hope you'll have more luck with it.

Comment: Just bear in mind, in that sample they're using Default Domain (`GetDefaultDomain`), which I think is a bad idea if you do injection. You'd need to create a new domain.